# Python - how to replace values greater and smaller than a particular value

Tags: python

How can I replace the values of a DataFrame if are smaller or greater than a particular value?

print(df)

```
name            seq1   seq11
0     seq102    -14     -5.99   
1     seq103    -5.25   -7.94
```

I want to set the values `<` than -8.5 to 1 and `>` than -8.5 to 0.

I tried this but all the values gets zero;

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
num = df._get_numeric_data() 
num[num < -8.50] = 1
num[num > -8.50] = 0
```

The desired output should be:

```
name            seq1   seq11
0     seq102      1       0   
1     seq103      0       0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
num.iloc[:,1:] = num.iloc[:,1:].applymap(lambda x: 1 if x < -8.50 else 0)
```

Note that values equal to `-8.50` will be set to zero here.

Answer (score 0):

```
def thresh(x):
    if(x < -8.5):
        return 1
    elif(x > -8.5):
        return 0
    return x

print(df[["seq1", "seq2"]].apply(thresh))
```

Comment: It's probably more efficient (and less verbose) to do this with a lambda function, especially since you're using `apply`.

Comment: I just assumed that it was strictly less than or strictly greater than, so there would be an elif. I don't think lambda functions can do elif right?

Comment: You can do it by inserting another if/else after the else operator, or just by stacking two `applymap`s.